# Error message: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Please help! I'm pretty new to this so this problem completely baffles me!

**Error message:** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's Black Son',twitter_account_date='2015-10-21 22:36:06' WHERE twitter_id='257771' at line 1

**Code:**

```html
<?php
//ini_set('display_errors', 0);
date_default_timezone_set('GMT');
require_once('config.php');
require("twitter/twitteroauth.php");


 $date=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
 $time=date('H:i:s');

/* MarketPlace Email Notification*/

$sql_t="SELECT description FROM  email_template WHERE template_id=15";
$result_tmp=mysql_query($sql_t) or die(mysql_error());
$roT=mysql_fetch_array($result_tmp);
$tempL=$roT['description'];

 $sql_m="SELECT t.screen_name,t.seller_twitter_account_id,s.email,t.created_at,t.mail_status FROM seller_twitter_account as t LEFT JOIN seller_master as s ON t.seller_id=s.seller_id WHERE t.tweet_price=0";
 $result_m=mysql_query($sql_m) or die(mysql_error());

 while($roM=mysql_fetch_array($result_m)){

     $screen_name=$roM['screen_name'];
  $twitter_act_id=$roM['seller_twitter_account_id'];
  $email=$roM['email'];
  $mail_status=$roM['mail_status'];
  $date1=strtotime($roM['created_at']);
  $date2=strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
  
  $diffHours = round(($date2 - $date1) / 60);

  if($diffHours>=1440 && $mail_status==0){
     $to = $email;
     $subject = "Add a Tweet Price";
     $message = str_replace("[SCREEN_NAME]",$screen_name,$tempL);
     $header = "From:info@tweetvend.com \r\n";
     $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
     $header .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
     $retval = mail ($to,$subject,$message,$header);
     if( $retval == true )  
     {
     echo "Message sent successfully...";
    mysql_query("UPDATE seller_twitter_account set mail_status=1 WHERE seller_twitter_account_id='$twitter_act_id'");
     }
     else
     {
     echo "Message could not be sent...";
     }

  }

    if($diffHours>=10080 && $mail_status==1){

     $to = $email;
     $subject = "Add a Tweet Price";
     $message = str_replace("[SCREEN_NAME]",$screen_name,$tempL);
     $header = "From:info@tweetvend.com \r\n";
     $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
     $header .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
     $retval = mail ($to,$subject,$message,$header);
     if( $retval == true )  
     {
     echo "Message sent successfully...";
      mysql_query("UPDATE seller_twitter_account set mail_status=2 WHERE seller_twitter_account_id='$twitter_act_id'");
     
     }
     else
     {
     echo "Message could not be sent...";
     }

  }




 }

 /* END code*/


/*UPDATE TWITTER ACCOUNT CODE*/

 $sql_tac="SELECT screen_name,oauth_access_token,oauth_access_token_secret,twitter_account_date FROM seller_twitter_account";
 $result_TAC=mysql_query($sql_tac);
 while($roWTA=mysql_fetch_array($result_TAC))
 {
   $twitterAccountDate=$roWTA['twitter_account_date'];
   $day1 =  strtotime(date("Y:m:d H:i:s"));
   $day2 = strtotime($twitterAccountDate);
   $diffHours = round(($day1 - $day2) / 3600);

if($diffHours>=24){

   $screen_name=$roWTA['screen_name'];
   $oauth_access_token =$roWTA['oauth_access_token'];
   $oauth_access_token_secret=$roWTA['oauth_access_token_secret'];
   $consumer_key='37pRttXuKrGZawYsNp6Tu6DSL';
   $consumer_secret='566TXt7ldNDJFkZazshwhgy3JILh104DP4KIUyrSguH5MZ54o1'; 
 
     $request = array(
            'screen_name'       => $screen_name,
            'count'             => '1'
        );

    $twitterObj = new TwitterOAuth($consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $oauth_access_token, $oauth_access_token_secret);
    $twitterInfo=$twitterObj->get('statuses/user_timeline',$request);

   //echo '<pre>';
    //print_r($twitterInfo); 
    //$twitterInfo->error==''

  if(!empty($twitterInfo)){
     //if(isset($twitterInfo->errors) && count($twitterInfo->errors)==0){

 if($twitterInfo->errors[0]->message==''){
  $twitter_id=$twitterInfo[0]->user->id;
  $name=$twitterInfo[0]->user->name;
  $num_of_followers=$twitterInfo[0]->user->followers_count;
  $num_of_followings=$twitterInfo[0]->user->friends_count;
  $num_of_tweets=$twitterInfo[0]->user->statuses_count;
  $twitter_profile_pic_url=$twitterInfo[0]->user->profile_image_url;
    
  $sqltUpdt="UPDATE seller_twitter_account SET num_of_followers='$num_of_followers', num_of_followings='$num_of_followings', num_of_tweets='$num_of_tweets', twitter_profile_pic_url='$twitter_profile_pic_url', twitter_name='$name',twitter_account_date='$date' WHERE twitter_id='$twitter_id'";
       mysql_query($sqltUpdt) or die(mysql_error());
     } 
   } 
 }
}

 /*END TWITTER ACCOUNT CODE*/

 /*Tweet Approved Automatically*/
 
 /*$sql_tweet="SELECT od.order_id,m.item_id,t.tweet_asap,t.retweet_asap,t.tweet_post_date_time,t.retweet_post_date,t.tweet_order_date from order_master as od,  item_order_master as m,tweet_order as t WHERE od.order_id=m.order_id AND m.item_id=t.item_id AND m.tweet_status=0 AND od.order_completed=1 AND od.is_active=1 group by m.item_id";

 $tweetResult=mysql_query($sql_tweet);
 while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($tweetResult)){
  $tweet_asap=$rows['tweet_asap'];
  $retweet_asap=$rows['retweet_asap'];
  $tweet_post_date=$rows['tweet_post_date_time'];
  $retweet_post_date=$rows['retweet_post_date'];
  $tweet_asap_post_date=$rows['tweet_order_date'];
  $orderId=$rows['order_id'];
  $itemId=$rows['item_id'];

   if($tweet_asap==1 || $retweet_asap==1){
   $day1 =  strtotime(date("Y:m:d H:i:s"));
   $day2 = strtotime($tweet_asap_post_date);
   $diffHours = round(($day1 - $day2) / 3600);
   if($diffHours>=48){
          $sql_up="UPDATE item_order_master set tweet_status=1 WHERE item_id='$itemId'";
     mysql_query($sql_up) or die(mysql_error());
     $sql_upp="UPDATE tweet_order set tweet_order_date='$date' WHERE item_id='$itemId'";
     mysql_query($sql_upp) or die(mysql_error());
   }
 }
 if($tweet_asap==0){
       $day1 =  strtotime(date("Y:m:d H:i:s"));
    $day2 = strtotime($tweet_post_date);
    $diffHours = round(($day1 - $day2) / 3600);
     if($diffHours>=48){
           $sql_up="UPDATE item_order_master set tweet_status=1 WHERE item_id='$itemId'";
     mysql_query($sql_up) or die(mysql_error());
     $sql_upp="UPDATE tweet_order set tweet_post_date_time='$date' WHERE item_id='$itemId'";
     mysql_query($sql_upp) or die(mysql_error());
   }
 }
 if($retweet_asap==0){
       $day1 =  strtotime(date("Y:m:d H:i:s"));
    $day2 = strtotime($retweet_post_date);
    $diffHours = round(($day1 - $day2) / 3600);
     if($diffHours>=48){
   $sql_up="UPDATE item_order_master set tweet_status=1 WHERE item_id='$itemId'";
     mysql_query($sql_up) or die(mysql_error());
     $sql_upp="UPDATE tweet_order set retweet_post_date='$date' WHERE item_id='$itemId'";
     mysql_query($sql_upp) or die(mysql_error());

   }
 }


 }*/

 /*End Code*/

 

echo 'Completed';


?>
```

Comment: What is the value of `$name`.

Comment: You're not escaping any input nor using prepared statements, which means if someone enters a `'`, your query breaks.

Comment: thanks for the quick responses Mike. How would I rectify the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape all the inputs, in case they contain quote characters.

```
$twitter_id = mysql_real_escape_string($twitterInfo[0]->user->id);
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($twitterInfo[0]->user->name);
... and so on
```

It would be better if you switched to PDO or mysqli, and used prepared statements with bound parameters, instead of substituting variables into query strings. See [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Thanks for the help! Especially so quickly :)